# How to implement fast majority voting for a bit matrix

Tags: opencv, hamming-distance, orb

I have a representation of a large bit matrix where I'd like to efficiently retrieve the majority bit for each matrix column (^= bit value that occurs most often). The background is that the matrix rows represent ORB feature descriptors and the value I'm looking for resembles the mean in the Hamming domain.

The implementation I'm currently working with looks like this

```
  // holds column-sum for each bit
  std::vector<int> sum(32 * 8, 0);

  // cv::Mat mat is a matrix of values € [0, 255] filled elsewhere
  for (size_t i = 0; i < mat.cols; ++i)
  {
    const cv::Mat &d = mat.row(i);
    const unsigned char *p = d.ptr<unsigned char>();

    // count bits set column-wise
    for (int j = 0; j < d.cols; ++j, ++p)
    {
      if (*p & (1 << 7)) ++sum[j * 8];
      if (*p & (1 << 6)) ++sum[j * 8 + 1];
      if (*p & (1 << 5)) ++sum[j * 8 + 2];
      if (*p & (1 << 4)) ++sum[j * 8 + 3];
      if (*p & (1 << 3)) ++sum[j * 8 + 4];
      if (*p & (1 << 2)) ++sum[j * 8 + 5];
      if (*p & (1 << 1)) ++sum[j * 8 + 6];
      if (*p & (1))      ++sum[j * 8 + 7];
    }
  }

  cv::Mat mean = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 32, CV_8U);
  unsigned char *p = mean.ptr<unsigned char>();

  const int N2 = (int)mat.rows / 2 + mat.rows % 2;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sum.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (sum[i] >= N2)
    {
      // set bit in mean only if the corresponding matrix column
      // contains more 1s than 0s
      *p |= 1 << (7 - (i % 8));
    }

    if (i % 8 == 7) ++p;
  }
```

The bottleneck is the big loop with all the bit shifting. Is there any way or known bit magic to make this any faster?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/5008845

Comment: I know this algorithm but I don't think it helps me much in this case. To be able to use it, I need some sort of contiguous bit sequence and I see no efficient way extracting the sequence of each i-th bit out of the j-th matrix column.